# type agnostic sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to have my sort function to be able to sort for numbers and for strings depending on the given array (the array type is not known until run-time)

I know that I can do a sort for an array of numbers by doing:

```
myList = [1,4,6,2,3]
if (sortDirection == "ASC"){
  myList.sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b;
  }
}
else if (sortDirection == "DESC") {
  myList.sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a;
  }
}
```

but myList can also be a list of strings and this would not work. I would have to do

```
myList = ["asdf", "sdfg", "dfgh"]
if (sortDirection == "ASC") {
  myList.sort();
}
else if (sortDirection == "DESC") {
  myList.sort();
  myList.reverse();
}
```

I can certainly do a type check whether the list is typeof string or typeof number and do a conditional and have all these cases but I feel like there is a better way to format all of these at once.

Also, if there is an easier way to do ASC (Ascending) and DESC (Descending) feature that would also be ideal rather than redeclaring the same function but in opposite ways.

Comment: The `.localeCompare()` method on the String prototype returns exactly the right sort of value for ascending ordering on strings.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834959/2813224) is very wrong. Review this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/L9hw06uf/) to see how bad it is. For a correct and complete answer see my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850578/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer that comes to my mind is to just indiscriminately do a string comparison when sorting. Javascript supports lexicographical string comparisons out of the box. This means that `'Z' > 'A'` will return `true`. [Look here for more info.](https://javascript.info/comparison)

Therefore, your sort function *could* look like this:

```js
function sortArray(isDescending = true) {
  return (a, b) => {
     if(a.toString().toLowerCase() > b.toString().toLowerCase()) {
         if (isDescending) {
             return 1
         } else {
             return -1
         }
     } else {
         if (isDescending) {
            return -1
         } else {
            return 1
         }
  }
}
```

Then, you could use your function like this:

```
const myArrayOfStringsOrNumbers = ['A', 2, 'Bob', 18];
myArrayOfStringsOrNumbers.sort(sortArray(true));
```

Comment: Ahh this suffice, I thought my sort wasn't working because it uses ASCII for string comparison which would group all the uppercase letters first before the lowercase so I also added a .toLowerCase() and worked perfectly!

Comment: @jimmyhuang0904 you were too hasty in accepting such a poorly written answer. You *could* use this answer if you don't mind the number 18 being placed before 2. The `isDescending` Boolean has no meaning...where is it being used? It uses the ASCII code values to derive it's ill begotten order. Plus, using `.toLowercase()` on the input kinda defeats the purpose of pure sorting -- no modification of the array elements. `['Aa', 'aa']` is not `['aa', 'aa']`. There's no [mcve] for this answer to see how it fails, so review it live at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/L9hw06uf/)

Comment: Test your code it doesn't sort correctly, although you managed to get the order switching working... but that's doesn't really mater if the result is still wrong. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/38ef6m1c/). Please tell me in what universe is `["Bob","A",2,18] ` or  `[18,2,"A","Bob"]` in correct order?

Answer (score -1):

Taking [@Pointy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) advice a further step, I made a sorting function based on the [Int.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) Object of the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl). The String method [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is akin to the Collator method [`.compare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/compare).

```
/**
 * @function sortChars(chars, desc, caps);
 * Sort an array of characters in a human readable order.
 *
 * @param  {Array}   chars An array of Strings and Numbers.
 * @param  {Boolean} desc  true - sort in descending order  
 * @default                false - sort in ascending order
 *                         
 * @param  {Boolean} caps  true - will place upper case letters first
 * @default                false - will place lower case letters first
 * @return {Array}         An array sorted by these criterion:
 *                         space: ' ', 
 *                         non-letters: '', 
 *                         numbers: 99,⁰
 *                         lower case letter: 'l',¹
 *                         upper case letter: 'L'¹
 *
 *//* ⁰Contiguous groups of digits are considered at that value as a whole inside 
       a String or Number ex. ['1', 99, '100A']
      ¹The order of case can be changed by the third parameter
 */
```

```js
const example = ['99', 98, 1, 'one', ' ', 'z', '♞', 'Ĉ', 'Z', 2112, '2111', 'a581', 'aa999999', '', 'One', 'aA999999'];

const sortChars = (chars, desc, caps) => {

  // Ternary to determine case order
  let caseType = !caps ? "lower" : "upper";

  /*
  Initializing Collator Object
  numeric: true and sensitivity: "base" are required
  to evaluate Numbers properly
  Refer to: https://blog.praveen.science/natural-sorting-in-javascript/
  */
  const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
    caseFirst: caseType,
    numeric: true,
    sensitivity: "base"
  });
  // Uncomment statement below to see option values 
  // log(check(collator, desc));
  const ordered = chars.sort(collator.compare);

  // Ternary to determine the direction of returned array
  return !desc ? ordered : ordered.reverse();
};

// Sort ascending order
log(sortChars(example));

// Sort descending order
log(sortChars(example, true));

// Sort ascending order and upper case first
log(sortChars(example, false, true));

// Utility to review the options object
function check(collator, desc) {
  return Object.assign(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(collator.resolvedOptions())), {
    descendingOrder: desc
  });
}

// Utility to log formatted entries to console
function log(data) {
  return console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  word-break: break-word
}
```